# Measuring rendering time in firefox

Tags: firefox, rendering, html-rendering

Is there any feature in firefox to measure rendering time ? I am doing a research for optimizing CSS, so i need to know how was the impact before and after optimizing CSS for rendering time.

I've tried the firefox dev tools and I didn't get anything that can show me the rendering time. I've also tried some plugin like firebug, gecko profiler, etc. And I still didn't get the rendering time. I didn't know whether I was wrong or maybe there was something I missed. Can somebody please show me the way if u got something that can measure the rendering time ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can open the dev tools, and see the performance tab. If you dont have it, enable it at the rights grind - opsions. There you can watch every render time of any function of any part of the page including memory

Comment: @Toumash Thanks for your reply. I still didn't get it. I mean to look for something like this image [http://i.imgur.com/LdNkYAz.png](http://i.imgur.com/LdNkYAz.png) . I got that from chrome, but i didn't find that from firefox. Is there any way to get that ?

Comment: I was going to post the screenshots, but this guys did it for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25239618/3711660

Comment: @Toumash okay I've visited that page and I've ever tried it too. It seems too complicated for me because i just wanted to get the rendering time. So the conclusion is that firefox 34 can't display the overall summary for rendering a webpage just like chrome did. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Perhaps you can define what you mean by "rendering."  Some take it to mean all client actions.  Some take it to mean the very strict definition in use by Google and Chrome.   Can you clarify

Answer (score 0):

The [app.telemetry Page Speed Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/apptelemetry) plugin looks quite a bit like the one in Chrome. It gives numerical values rather than graphs, but it accomplishes the same task.